# Cannot build Boost with MinGW

Tags: boost, build, installation, mingw

I just downloaded the latest versions of MinGW and Boost 1.54.0 (on Windows 7).
The first one installed smoothly (g++ 4.7.2).

When installing Boost, this is all I get:

```
boost_1_54_0> bootstrap.bat mingw
Building Boost.Build engine
The system cannot find the batch label specified - Test_Option
\CMake was unexpected at this time.
```

The compiler's path is set (from any directory, g++.exe --version returns 4.7.2).

Is there anything wrong in the way I specify MinGW?

Comment: [Here](http://www.blinnov.com/en/2010/06/04/microsoft-was-unexpected-at-this-time/) you can find a similar problem. "So, the fist thing you should do if you’re having the same problem: look at your %PATH% environment variable and check if anything is enclosed in double quotes.".

Comment: @cv_and_he - It fixed my problem. If you put it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. I wouldn't know what to put in the answer. If you know exactly the problem and what you must do to solve it put it as an answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: @cv_and_he - As an answer you can just copy your first comment.